# Laravel5: what's better, class names as strings or Classname::class

Tags: php, class, laravel, namespaces

In many files in Laravel, maybe in other frameworks, too, you have to specify a class name.

You can either write it with "::class"

```
App\Models\User::class
```

or as String:

```
'App\Models\User'
```

Well, with the first variant, the class will be loaded right away when it occures. With the second variant I guess it will be loaded when it's going to be used.

Which one is better or recommended? In the Laravel default config files always the "::class" variant is used.

Comment: Be aware that `::class` constant is only available on PHP 5.5 and upwards.

Answer (score 2):

No, actually `App\Models\User::class` is the better approach because the `::class` returns the fully qualified name of a class. This is more convenient and less error prone. For example:

```
namespace Some\Name\Space;

use vendor\package\Foo;
use vendor\package\Bar;

class Foo {

    public  function  someMethod()
    {
        // You can't use app('Bar'), You need the FQN
        // So it's possible using the following approach
        $bar = app(Bar::CLASS); // vendor\package\Bar
        $foo = new Foo($bar);

    }
}
```

This is easily possible to get the class using it's fully qualified name just using `Bar::CLASS`, so, `app(Bar::CLASS)` will become `app('vendor\package\Bar')`.

Comment: ...not mentioning that with `Bar::CLASS` you can also use autocomplete on your IDE ;)